# Concatenate Swift Array of Int to create a new Int

Tags: arrays, swift, int

How can you make an `Array<Int>` (`[1,2,3,4]`) into a regular `Int` (`1234`)? I can get it to go the other way (splitting up an `Int` into individual digits), but I can't figure out how to combine the array so that the numbers make up the digits of a new number.

Answer (score 16):

This will work:

```
let digits = [1,2,3,4]
let intValue = digits.reduce(0, combine: {$0*10 + $1})
```

**For Swift 4+ :**

```
let digits = [1,2,3,4]
let intValue = digits.reduce(0, {$0*10 + $1})
```

Or this compiles in more versions of Swift:

(Thanks to Romulo BM.)

```
let digits = [1,2,3,4]
let intValue = digits.reduce(0) { return $0*10 + $1 }
```

---

**NOTE**

This answer assumes all the Ints contained in the input array are digits -- 0...9 . Other than that, for example, if you want to convert `[1,2,3,4, 56]` to an Int `123456`, you need other ways.

Comment: I tried this with the following array [1,2,3,4, 56] and it gave me 12396 so I believe this might not work with int values with more than one digit

Comment: This answer is dedicated for the case each Int is representing a single digit of decimal number. I thought naming `digits` was expressing the requirement for my answer...

Comment: I see. I assumed the question was for a more generic way to combine Int arrays (of any number of digits) to one. Not specifically for converting an Int Array *back* to an single Integer.

Comment: @Prientus, reading the question again, the OP is not clear enough about the requirement. The writers should consider how readers would think. I will add some note about the requirement of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can go through string conversion too:

```
Int(a.map(String.init).joined())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
let digitsArray = [2, 3, 1, 5]
if let number = Int.init(d.flatMap({"\($0)"}).joined()) {
    // do whatever with <number>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution

```
let nums:[UInt] = [1, 20, 3, 4]
if let value = Int(nums.map(String.init).reduce("", combine: +)) {
    print(value)
}
```

This code also works if the values inside the `nums` array are bigger than `10`.

```
let nums:[UInt] = [10, 20, 30, 40]
if let value = Int(nums.map(String.init).reduce("", combine: +)) {
    print(value) // 10203040
}
```

> This code required the `nums` array to contain only **non** negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
let number = [1, 2, 3].reduce(0){ $0 * 10 + $1 }

print("result: \(number)") // result: 123
```