# Swift build hexadecimal from array (active/inactive states) of Int and get an integer form hexadecimal

Tags: ios, swift, hex

Let say we can mark weekend day active or inactive. I need to use Integer to say system that I marked day active or inactive, to retrieve this integer I need to use array `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. So if you see at this array all day of week marked as active and in Hexadecimal it's `0000007F`.

If I use `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]` this string it means Hexadecimal = `00000001`. So my question is how to create Hexadecimal from array and then get form it an `Integer`. So in case with `0000007F` it should be 127.

I assume that it should be something like that:

let array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
let hexadecimal = array.toHexadecimal
let intNumber = hexadecimal.toInt

print(intNumber) // prints 127

Also I guess it can be for example an array with ints like [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] wich means that Monday and from Wednesday till Saturday (including) are active days.

Comment: Swift has bit shift operators. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: @johnelemans, thanks for comment, but for example how to build it. For example if I have an array of [0, 1, 0, 1 ... ]  how to get right value `let bits: UInt8 = ` *0b11111100* ? I don't know how to transform it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27191772/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks for comment. it's ok if you know how to get `F00`, but I don't know how to do it, I know that I have array of checked object and I need to get an Int. My system does not know what is F or B, it's just a set of 0101010 which is active or not. remove string from question to get rid confusion.

Comment: @johnelemans removed string from question to get rid of confusion.

Comment: examples  bits = bits << 1 moves all the bits to the left by 1. bits = bits | 1 will set bit 1 to one and leave the others as is.

Comment: @johnelemans, thanks for comments, not sure I am cleat in my question, but for example, I am not sure what you mean leave the others, I have an array of ints `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]` and I don't know how to get bites from it.

Comment: try `Int([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].map{String($0)}.joined(), radix: 2)` will return 127

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks, Value of type '[String]' has no member 'joined'

Comment: update your Xcode. Xcode 8 GM is already available for developers

Comment: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].reduce(0, combine: {$0*2 + $1})` would also work and probably faster than map

Comment: `String([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].reduce(0, combine: {$0*2 + $1}), radix: 16)` if you need the hexa string `"7f"`

Comment: @LeoDabus nice! sounds like a magic!!!!!0 thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123176/discussion-between-matrosov-alexander-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce method to sum up your binary array (inspired at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165603/2303865)) and use String(radix:) initializer to convert your integer to hexa string:

**Swift 3 • Xcode 8 or later**

```
let binaryArray =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

let integerValue = binaryArray.reduce(0, {$0*2 + $1})
let hexaString = String(integerValue, radix: 16)  // "7f"
```

Comment: what's behind Swift 3 eliminating `combine` doesn't it help make code more readable?

Comment: how to easy revert back from int to array?

Comment: @Prcela `if let int = Int(hexaString, radix: 16),
let binary = String(int, radix: 2).map(\.wholeNumberValue) {`