# Change Array of Int to String so it can be put into a label.text

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I have an array:

```
var numberArray = [1,2,3]
```

I want to convert this into a string and put it into a label text:

```
label.text = "123"
```

I've already tried for loops / other things online. Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38165569/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this using higher order functions [`Map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) and `Reduce`

```
label.text = numberArray.map{ String($0) }.reduce("", +)
```

Or you can use [joined()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945737-joined) as well

```
label.text = numberArray.map{String($0)}.joined()
```

You can also use map this way

```
label.text = numberArray.map(String.init).joined()
```

Comment: I did try map before but wasn't using reduce and obviously was doing it wrong. Cheers!

Comment: Joined is definitely the better option. It doesn't matter for these small sizes, but reduce has quadratic time complexity, because it makes a new string on every step of the computation. That would be a big deal for larger datasets

Comment: Yes @Alexander-ReinstateMonica you are perfectly right