# How can I return a combined Int from an [Int] array?

Tags: swift

I have an `[Int]` array like so:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

How can I apply a function on this so it returns:

```
123
```

?

Comment: Do you need `123` as an `Int` or `String`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165569/concatenate-swift-array-of-int-to-create-a-new-int

Comment: As an `Int` @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
let nums = [1, 2, 3]
let combined = nums.reduce(0) { ($0*10) + $1 }
print(combined)
```

**Caveats**

- Make sure the `Int` won't overflow if the number gets too long (+2<sup>63</sup> on a 64-bit system).
- You need to also be careful all numbers in the list aren't more than 9 (a single base-10 digit), or this arithmetic will fail. Use the `String` concatenation technique to ensure that all base-10 numbers are correctly handled. But, again, you need to be careful that the number won't overflow if you choose to convert it back to an `Int`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it complicates the example and is a non-issue if only used for small use-cases like OP demonstrates (there are also a variety of possible failure-modes, which depend on OP's use case).

Comment: Yeah you're correct, it was misleading being at the start.

Comment: This assumes all integers in the collection are from 0 to 9. `[1, 2, 32]` would result in 152

Comment: @LeoDabus Very true. Answer is edited.

Answer (score 1):

We can do like below...

```
var finalStr = ""
    [1,2,3].forEach {
        finalStr.append(String($0))
    }
    if let number = Int(finalStr) {
        print(number)
    }
```

Comment: This can be simplified using `map`: `let number = Int([1,2,3].map(String.init).joined())`